# How to store a class object into Internal Memory Storage using serializable?

Tags: java, android, serialization, objectoutputstream

I need to store this object into the internal storage memory of the phone, and i have the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` set on the manifest. The object itself haves two static methods for store and reload it from the internal memory:

```
public class SaveState implements Serializable {
static public List<FullMagazine> fms = new ArrayList<FullMagazine>();
static SaveState instance=null;

public static SaveState getInstance(){      
    if( instance == null )
        instance = new SaveState();     
    return instance;
}

public static void saveData(SaveState instance){
    ObjectOutput out;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("appSaveState.data"));        
        out.writeObject(instance);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static SaveState loadData(){
    ObjectInput in;
    SaveState ss=null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("appSaveState.data"));       
        ss=(SaveState) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return ss;
}
}
```

I'm trying to store it and reopen it using this call in my activity:

```
            SaveState.fms.add(fm);
            SaveState.saveData(SaveState.getInstance());                
            SaveState sv = SaveState.loadData();
```

But it is not working, it is not storing the object, and ofcourse it is not reading the objecto, i'm getting these two exception while storing and reading the object:

```
    03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /appSaveState.data (Read-only file system)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:168)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:147)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at com.Magazine.SaveState.saveData(SaveState.java:35)
03-23 09:18:16.702: WARN/System.err(9060):     at com.Magazine.MainMenu$DownloadThread.run(MainMenu.java:807)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /appSaveState.data (No such file or directory)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at com.Magazine.SaveState.loadData(SaveState.java:46)
03-23 09:18:16.709: WARN/System.err(9060):     at com.Magazine.MainMenu$DownloadThread.run(MainMenu.java:809)
```

What's wrong in the code?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to write to / which is read only in android.

Comment: Does the class used in the static List, `FullMagazine` also implements Serializable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("appSaveState.data"));
```

with

```
   File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "appSaveState.data");
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
```

as correctly pointed out by @e-x, the file will not be removed clearing application's data or uninstalling the app

Comment: and what happens if the phone doesn't have a SDCARD installed? i'm trying to store it on the internal memory storage because i must store this data on all the phones, including the phones without SDCARD

Comment: if you are referring to mobile phones without sdcard support (like the samsung nexus s), the Enviromenet.getExternalStorageDirectory() will return the path to the phone internal storage archive.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if the phone has an SDCARD then the file will remain when clearing the application's data.

Comment: @E_X, I updated the answer, thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to just write into the internal storage (even if you get that permission).
Try it with the external sd or your [cache folder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getCacheDir%28%29) instead.

Comment: Cachefolder data is persisent until the app is uninstalled from the phone? tell me how to do it with the cache folder please, what i should change into my code?

Comment: File cacheFile = new File(activity.getCacheDir(), "appSaveState.data"); - write into that file like you did before.

Comment: Cachefolder is prone to be deleted by OS when free space is becoming low!

Answer (score 1):

This was my aproach based on this post and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SerializationwithObjectInputStreamandObjectOutputStream.htm)

I wrote this on my User class

```
private static File mFolder;
public void saveData(Activity pContext) {
    //this could be initialized once onstart up
    if(mFolder == null){
        mFolder = pContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    }
    this.save();
    ObjectOutput out;
    try {
        File outFile = new File(mFolder,
                "someRandom.data");
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
        out.writeObject(this);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static User loadData(Context pContext) {
    if(mFolder == null){
        mFolder = pContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    }
    ObjectInput in;
    User lUser = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(mFolder.getPath() + File.separator + "someRandom.data");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        lUser = (User) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (lUser != null) {
        lUser.save();
        Log.d("current User: ", lUser.nickname);
    } else {
        Log.d("current User: ", "null");
    }
    return lUser;
}
```

Edit:

Then from my activity i call

```
mUser = User.loadData(mSelf);
```

or

```
mUser = User.loadData(this);
```

mSelf would be an instance I store

Hope this helps :)