# How to save entire objects to SD card in Android

Tags: android, object, sd-card

Hey all my fellow geeks out there!

I need to save objects from my Android app to the SD card. I have searched a lot about this in google, but I dont seem to find anything. I only find how to save primitive types, but not entire objects with all its related attributes.

What I have is:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setBirthYear(2009);
dog.setName("Pluto");
```

I need to save this Dog-object to the SD card and retrieve it when needed, with all the related attributes.

I would be very happy if code samples for saving and retrieving the object could be provided.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should read about serialization - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See links below, these are related to your problem

[Some object don't save to Android internal memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416650/some-object-dont-save-to-android-internal-memory)

[How to store a class object into Internal Memory Storage using serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836663/how-to-store-a-class-object-into-internal-memory-storage-using-serializable)

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the links

Answer (score 1):

With [ObjectOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) you can serialize objects in files.